# How to subset a dataset in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which has more than 10 million raws composed of about 30 columns.

The first column is ID

```
ID   C
1    1
1    2
1    3
1    2
1    3
2    1
2    5
2    9
2    0
2    1
```

I would like to extract only the first four rows of each ID(they are the newest inputs as it is already sorted)

I am currently using the below code, but unfortunately it is so slow as it takes about two hours to process about 5% of the data and it may take a day or so to process the whole data.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame() # an empty dataframe
for i in df.ID:   # df is the dataframe which contains the data
    df2 = df[df["ID"]== i] 
    df2 = df2[0:4] # take the first four rows
    df_f = df1.append(df2)
```

Are there an effecient way to do the same thing in a shorter time.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there are at least four instances of each ID?

Comment: Yes there are more than 10 instances for most IDs and I want to get instances from the last four months only and instances are already sorted in a descending order for each ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `head()` method:

```
df.groupby("ID").head(4)
```

[image]

Here is a revised version of your original code with run time testing against `groupby().head()` method:

```
def loop():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame() # an empty dataframe
    for i in df.ID.drop_duplicates():   # df is the dataframe which contains the data
        df2 = df[df["ID"]== i] 
        df2 = df2[0:4] # take the first four rows
        df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
    return df1

%timeit loop()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 1.99 ms per loop

%timeit df.groupby("ID").head(4)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 485 µs per loop
```

Comment: I used your code:

    df.groupby("ID").head(4)

It solves my problem without using a loop.
Thanks so much.